# Opera needs to long forms authentification timeout

Tags: forms, authentication, web-config, timeout, opera

I have a problem with forms authentification in Opera. There is my forms configuration in Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/User/LogOn" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

In this case in Opera I will be succesfully logged in. But at the same time I will be redirected to "~/User/LogOn" action at once! The next configuration helps me to avoid this behavior in Opera:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/User/LogOn" timeout="1000" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

In this case all works fine, and authentification passes me to other actions. The 30 minutes timeout suits me at all. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our admin has found out the issue. It seems that server system time lags behind for one day, so every time cookie was already dead with 30 minutes timeout. Now all works fine. But we still do not know, why that issue has appeared just in Opera Browser (v. 12.02, 12.16).